# Update div var after onInput React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to Stack Overflow and to React and would need some help.

I started a little project for learning React JS. In this project I can enter a text and this text will be displayed but hashed (The hash function is selfmade and is just a simulation). Everything works fine except it will not display the text at the second last line ( `<div>{ hashedText }</div>`). It seems like I have to update it but I don't know how. Any hints?

`code`

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const TextInput = () => {
  let hashedText = "";
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const getInput = (string) => {
    setText(string);
    hashedText = hash(string);
    console.log("this works");
  };
  // Hasher
  const hash = (string) => {
    console.log("you made it");
    //set variable hash as 0
    var hash = 0;
    // if the length of the string is 0, return 0
    if (string.length === 0) return hash;
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      let ch = string.charCodeAt(i);
      hash = (hash << 5) - hash + ch;
      hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-control">
      <h1>Hasher</h1>
      <label>Text</label>
      <input
        onInput={(e) => getInput(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Informations"
      ></input>
      <label>Hash</label>
      <div>{hashedText}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

Comment: I have a question about your state `const [text, setText] = useState("");`. It seems you never use the variable `text`. Why? If you do not need to store the real variable to use it then why not store the hashed value in it instead of a `hashedText`? Cuz right now you have a state variable that you never read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue accures because of your local variable `hashedText`. A components re-renders when you update a state or because of some other hook like `useEffect` and etc. In this case even tho you fire the `useState` hook, you do NOT read the state variable `text` anywhere. React optimizes the cod to try to re-render as minimum as possible and since `text` is not used - it dosent update anything including your `hashedText`.

To solve this you need to store your hashed variable in a state or read it, and hash it, off the state itself instead of passing props to the method.

Can do this to store hashed

```
const getInput = (string) => {
    setText(hash(string));
  };
```

Or use `useEffect` hook

```
  const [hashedText, setHashedText] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  
  const getInput = (string) => {
    setText(string);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setHashedText(hash(text));
  }, [text]);
```

On addition, would recommend using `onChange={(e) => getInput(e.target.value)}`, on the `<input>`, instead of `onInput` AND do not use `var` but instead `let` and `const`. So instead of `var hash = 0;` => `let hash = 0;`. `var` is old and unsafe. Since you are using `es6` JS - you should stick with `es6` standards instead of adding older onces

Answer (score 1):

React re renders the component's html only if the `state` or `props` changes. So I suggest to keep the `hashedText` in the local state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't store the state for the hashedText. You just assign the empty string as a value to it when the component has mounted or updated. Try the following code.

```
function TextInput() {
  const [hashedText, setHashedText] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
 
  function getInput(string) {
    setText(string)
    setHashedText(hash(string))
    console.log('this works')
  }

  // Hasher
  function hash(string) {
    console.log('you made it')
     //set variable hash as 0
     var hash = 0;
     // if the length of the string is 0, return 0
     if (string.length === 0) return hash;
     for (let i = 0 ;i<string.length ; i++) {
         let ch = string.charCodeAt(i);
         hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + ch;
         hash = hash & hash;
     }
     return hash
  }  

  return (
    <div className='form-control'>
        <h1>Hasher</h1>
        <label>Text</label>
        <input onInput={e=> getInput(e.target.value)}
        type='text' 
        placeholder='Enter Informations'></input>
        <label>Hash</label>
        <div>{hashedText}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChange` event (or not), `input` is **self-closing** tag

```js
const getInput = v => {
    setText(hash(v))
};
```

```html
<input
    onChange={e=> getInput(e.target.value)}
    type='text' 
    placeholder='Enter Informations'
/>
<label>{text}</label>
```